# Would it be possible to separate key generation and connection of HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, proxy

I know generally how HTTPS works, and from what I read, it seems that the generation of the encryption key could be done by a computer that isn't the one establishing the connection.

My thought is to create a proxy that isn't actually able to see the traffic going over the SSL connection. To do this, you would have a handshake in the same way as usual between the proxy and the server. However you would pass the encrypted symmetrical key to the proxy from your computer who would then transmit it on to the server. Then, when the server returned an encrypted payload, the proxy would not be able to decrypt it, but would forward it on to the users computer.

Am I missing something fundamental about how HTTPS works?

Comment: Not a programming question and thus off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic at stackoverflow.com. A better site to ask such questions is security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: congratulations ... that's what (normaly) happens when a proxy forwards HTTPS or generally TLS traffic ... it just relays the messages and can't decrypt them ...

Comment: Great! Thanks for the response @DarkSquirrel42. I couldn't find direct reference